# How can I automatically quote or group commandline arguments for alias in bash?

Tags: bash, alias

I have a script that takes a command and executes it on a remote host.  It works fine, for example:

```
$ rexec "ant build_all"
```

will execute the "ant build_all" command on the remote system (passing it through SSH, etc).

Because I'm lazy, I want to set up an alias for this command (and ultimately, several others), such that, for example, I can just invoke

```
$ rant build_all
```

and bash will it will automatically invoke

```
$ rexec "ant build_all"
```

I tried doing this with alias, but if I define

```
alias rant=rexec ant
```

then any arguments passed to "rant" will just be appended to the end, like so:

```
$ rant build_all -Dtarget=Win32
(interpreted as:)
$ rexec "ant" build_all -Dtarget=Win32
```

This fails, because rexec really takes just one argument, and ignores the others.

I could probably do this with a bash wrapper script, but I was wondering if bash had any built-ins for doing this for me, perhaps a named-argument version of alias, or a perl-like quote string command (e.g. qw/ / ), or some such.

Comment: actually, I left out some important information:  rexec is actually an alias for another command, like so:

    alias rexce="run_remote.sh -c"

but it still takes a single string as an argument.  This is important for the accepted solution, below, with my modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all arguments, this will work.

```
function rant () {
    rexec "ant $*"
}
```

You may need to adjust the quoting, depending on what arguments you're passing.

Comment: I used this, but with an important generalization.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using Ken G's answer, but one better:  defining rex as a function, like so:

```
function rex {
    run_remote.sh -c "$*"
}
```

allowed me to then use rexec in aliases, like this:

```
alias rant="rex ant"
```

and still have it wrap the arguments up the way I need them.

I forgot I could use functions like that in bash.  This does exactly what I needed, without having to create a wrapper script.

Great tip, thanks!

edit:  changed "rexec" to "rex", because I found that my system already had a program called "rexec"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a function, not an alias:

```
function rant { rexec "ant $1"; }
```

You can call it at the command line like an alias